Angular 18 falsely throwing a routing error, despite the routes previously working fine
Background:
I'm integrating a login component that includes Google authentication. Upon successful authentication, user information is obtained, a token is generated, and then sent to the backend for processing. Here's the relevant TypeScript code:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from '../app.routes';

declare var google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-log-in',
  templateUrl: './log-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./log-in.component.css']
})
export class LogInComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    (window as any)['handleCredentialResponse'] = this.handleCredentialResponse.bind(this);
  }

  handleCredentialResponse(response: any): void {
    const idToken = response.credential;
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/login', { id_token: idToken })
      .subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          console.log('Success:', data);
          // Handle success (e.g., store user info, redirect to dashboard)
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        },
        (error: any) => {
          console.error('Error:', error);
        }
      );
  }
}

THE PROBLEM
After integrating the above TypeScript code, my Angular application fails to launch with the error:
"NG04014: Invalid configuration of route 'login'. One of the following must be provided: component, loadComponent, redirectTo, children or loadChildren."
Previously, my routes worked correctly without this issue. Below are my current routes:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';
import { LogInComponent } from './log-in/log-in.component';
import { DashBoardComponent } from './dash-board/dash-board.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LogInComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashBoardComponent },
  { path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }


Minor request:
I would appreciate a quick review of the handleCredentialResponse function to ensure it's correctly implemented? I haven't been able to verify it due to the routing issue.
Thank you!

Maybe try to replace redirectTo: '/login' with redirectTo: 'login' ?

I have tried that; however the same issue persists, with the same error shown above, even after implementing the change you suggested! any other suggestions?

It seems your Routes are wrongly configured.
Try changing
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' }

to
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },

UPDATE
The solution was to change the routing inside the LoginComponent from
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);

to
this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');


I have tried that; however the same issue persists, with the same error shown above, even after implementing the change you suggested! any other suggestions? It is also a bit weird that it asking for "component, loadComponent, redirectTo, children or loadChildren" while I literally provided a component...?

You said After integrating the above TypeScript code your routing failed. Did the Login Route work before implementing the Logic inside the Component?

Yes, it did, it would load the html log in page which had a Google sign in, when the Google sign in is finished it would send for the back end, which would redirect the user to the dashboard route, which also used to work just fine. After integrating the typescript code to generate token etc...the routes stopped working...

Can you try to change the routing in the subscription to this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard'); and maybe remove the AppRoutingModule import if you dont need it in the component?

That worked, thanks a lot for your help, I tried researching why it worked and it was something about absolute vs relative paths, something I do not understand just yet. Your help is appreciated!
